# mongodb mapreduce script to count total orders fails

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm new to mongodb and I'm planning to migrate from SQL to noSQL. I've a lot of stored procs and I think mapReduce is the "equivalent" in noSQL world.
I've started with a js script that tries to count orders by customer, but it gives wrong result.
The script is:

```
db = connect("localhost:27017/pgi");                

for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
    db.orders.insert(
    {
        "cust_id"   : 1,
        "total" : 100,
    });
}

for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
    db.orders.insert(
    {
        "cust_id"   : 2,
        "total" : 100,
    });
}

var res = db.orders.find({cust_id : 1});    
print("Total Orders for customer 1:" + res.count());                        

var res = db.orders.find({cust_id : 2});    
print("Total Orders for customer 2:" + res.count());    

//map reduce
var map = function(){
  emit(this.cust_id, 1);
}

var reduce = function(key, values){
    var c = 0;
    for (index in values) {
        c += 1;
    }
    return {cust_id : key, count: c};
}

var res = db.orders.mapReduce(  
                        map, 
                        reduce, 
                        { 
                            out : {inline : 1} 
                        }
            );

res.find({}).forEach(function(item){ 
    printjson(item); 
});
```

the expected output is 1000 for each customer but I'm getting this:

```
connecting to: test 
connecting to: localhost:27017/pgi 
Total Orders for customer 1:1000 
Total Orders for customer 2:1000 
{ "_id" : 1, "value" : { "cust_id" : 1, "count" : 101 } } 
{ "_id" : 2, "value" : { "cust_id" : 2, "count" : 101 } }
```

Could someone kindly tell me what was wrong.
Regards,

Comment: Map/reduce is not the equivalent of stored procedures. For this simple job the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/#aggregation) is much simpler to use.

Comment: that's why I put equiv between quotes.
I think I've to use Aggregation in the long run, because my needs are much more complicated than a simple count of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MapReduce it's essential that the reducer output is of the same format as the mapper output value as the reducer may run multiple times for the same key. Also, the reducer does not need to output the key, only the resulting value after performing whatever operations are required on the input array.

So in your case the mapper looks correct for counting orders by customer, but the reducer should just output the total count rather than generating an Object with the key and count.

Also the reducer needs to sum the value of each `index`, not increment by 1, to handle the case where it is operating on the output of previous  invocations of the reduce function.

```
var reduce = function(key, values){
    var c = 0;
    for (var index in values) {
       c += values[index];
    }
    return c;
}
```